# Add jQuery DataTable to Asp.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want add jQuery DataTable (http://www.datatables.net/) to my mvc4 site. But it's doesn't work. Doesn't show anything, table look like before adding script.

FireBug show an error:

> TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

```
**Admin_panel.cshtml**

@model IEnumerable<Rejestracja_imprez.Models.User>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PanelAdmin.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
}

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
            });
        </script>


<table id="myDataTable">
....
```

In html page it's work good.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            } );
        </script>
    </head>

    <body >

<table id="example" >
...
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In what way does it not work?  How does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  When you do some debugging, what specifically is unexpected in the runtime values?

Comment: Table doesn't show anything, table look like before adding script. Nothing changed. FireBug show an error: `TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function`

Comment: According to that error, there is no function called `dataTable` on the jQuery object.  Did the JavaScript file for that plugin get loaded?  Did the JavaScript file for jQuery get loaded?  (Probably, if it got to that function call.)  Are there version conflicts between the two?  Is that the correct usage of the plugin?  You need to debug this in your browser.  If you can show a live example of the problem we might be able to help identify what's wrong.

Comment: Is function called `dataTable`. I make a simple html page using this jQuery and it is working good. I update main post with html page where it's work good.

Comment: That was one of several potential issues.  Have you confirmed that the JavaScript code is being loaded in the non-working version?  Honestly, you have to do some debugging.  Insisting that "it doesn't work" isn't getting anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved ;D

I add jQuery script to BundleConfig.cs in App_Start folder.

```
 **BundleConfig.cs**

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/table").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"));

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        ............
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.dataTables.css"));
```

In Admin_panel.cshtml I add:

```
**Admin_panel.cshtml**

@section Scripts {

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
        });
        </script>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are...

- Typo in file paths
- Problem with the linked stylesheet in body of page (try rendering in head of master layout via section)
- Order of loading resources into page
- Something wrong/missing in additional layout page

Actually you're trying to call a method which doesn't exist at this time.

You could try referencing the files your razor view via generated path (i.e. `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js")`)

If this is not working you can try adding the files in sections and render this sections in layout page (at the appropriate part of the markup!).